# How do I stop the AccentColor from turning Gray when a sheet is being presented?

Tags: swift, user-interface, swiftui, accent-color

When a sheet is presented in SwiftUI, my AccentColor (set in the asset catalog) turns gray on the view behind the sheet. Is there a way to disable this so that the AccentColor is always the set color, and does not change to gray when in the background?

I’ve noticed that if I use `Color(“AccentColor”)` the color doesn’t turn gray, but if I use `Color.accentColor` it does turn gray.

Comment: You've already answered your own question

Comment: No, the issue is that anything that uses the default AccentColor still turns gray, and I am asking if there is a way to disable this.

Answer (score 1):

**Color.accentColor** reflects the accent color of the system or app, it is a broad theme color applied to views and controls, so it relies on SwiftUI's default behavior, which may lead to the color being adjusted to match the background context. When you explicitly code **Color("AccentColor")** you are basically overriding this, that is why the color remains consistent. I guess you are not supposed to disable anything; you just need to define your own custom accent color.